# Assigning Custom Font to TextView

Tags: android, fonts

I'm new to programming and I'm looking to add a custom font I download to Android Studio. I was able to follow instructions how to add the font but when I run the app I can only get one TextView of my two two TextViews to use this font. This is my code, can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here. Thank you!

```js
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView text, text2;
    Typeface tfc1, tfc2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.top_text);
        text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_text);

        tfc1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/StarWars.ttf");
        text.setTypeface(tfc1);

        tfc1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/StarWars.ttf");
        text2.setTypeface(tfc2);



    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume there's a typo. You wrote *tfc1* but you set *tfc2*. From your code:

```
tfc1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/StarWars.ttf");
            text2.setTypeface(tfc2);
```

As both of the *tfc1* and *tfc2* fonts are same. You can use one typeface to both of the textviews as @Sagar Patel showed.

Answer (score 0):

**STEP 1/**

Start by creating a folder named `assests` then inside that folder create another one named `folder` and import your `*.ttf` files to that folder

**STEP 2/**

Now import this before start writing the code given below:

```
import android.graphics.Typeface;
```

Now implement the following code to your class:

```
// Font path
String fontPath = "fonts/Face Your Fears.ttf";

// text view label
TextView txtGhost = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.ghost);

// Loading Font Face
Typeface tf = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(), fontPath);

// Applying font
txtGhost.setTypeface(tf);
```

I suggest you follow this tutorial [right here](https://www.androidhive.info/2012/02/android-using-external-fonts/) it will guide step-by-step through using external fonts in Android Studio

Comment: I am having the same issue with these steps. I can only get my TextView id= top_text to use the font.

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial [link](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GPMDHz8MJvg) helps to understand on configuring the custom font in android.

[image]

[image: Custom Font for android textview]

Answer (score 0):

You can use `android:fontFamily` attribute in xml file.

Comment: It will be applicable only to minSDK >= 21

Comment: Yes. So which minversion you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
TextView text, text2;
    Typeface tfc1, tfc2;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.top_text);
        text2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.bottom_text);

        tfc1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/StarWars.ttf");
        text.setTypeface(tfc1);

      //  tfc1 = Typeface.createFromAsset(getAssets(),"fonts/StarWars.ttf");
     //you get error in this line   text2.setTypeface(tfc2);

       text2.setTypeface(tfc1);
    }
}
```